# How to run an ASP.NET app that has its layers separated?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, dll

I have to work on a project that is written in ASP.NET and Angular. I have some experience in ASP.NET Core, but this project is almost 5 years old, and when I open it in Visual Studio, the solution contains 4 folders with name of layers (like Business object layer or UI layer).

And the content of each of them are separate library project. I think these are dll of each layer, but how can I run them together? Each of them has a `App.config` file that I changed SQL connection of them.

Comment: Are you sure each of them has a web.config file? Does Visual Studio say that they're class libraries?

Comment: I made a mistake, I meant App.config

Comment: If those layers (as class libraries) are referenced by your ASP.NET project, then you don't have to do anything special at all - just run the web app, all dependent class libraries will be rebuilt (if needed), referenced and loaded as needed - nothing needs to be done on your part

Comment: thanks! one of them called other projects and their dll, so I set that project action as "start" in properties of solution, but now I have problem with migration, when I click on start, it show error about some FK constraints and no any table is created. mainly how can I migrate database using entity framework

Comment: That would be a seperate question, assuming you can't resolve it via adequate research. Please don't cram multiple questions into one, and make sure you adequately research and experiment before asking: if you ask a question for every roadblock you reach, it's going to be slow going.

Comment: If your "Layers" / are "projects", than it should be fine if you have a reference to those projects. When you're ready to deploy to this webapplication of yours, you have to publish this web Project to this webapplication. 

What do you mean with "And the content of each of them are separate library project"? Each project should generate a DLL when you build and compile your solution.